# fishシェルでanyenvを設定したときにcalled during startupエラーが出る

Tags: shell

昨日からfishシェルを使い始めまして、anyenvの設定を `~/.config/fish/config.fish` に記述しました。

```
set -x PATH $HOME/.anyenv/bin $PATH
eval (anyenv init - fish)
```

そしてfishを起動すると、以下のエラーがでました。

```
Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use "$PATH".
- (line 1): begin; source "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/libexec/../completions/anyenv.fish" function anyenv   set command $argv[1]   set -e argv[1]    command anyenv "$command" $argv end set -x GOENV_ROOT "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/goenv" set -x PATH $PATH "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/goenv/bin" export PATH="/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/goenv/shims:${PATH}" goenv rehash 2>/dev/null set -x NDENV_ROOT "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/ndenv" set -x PATH $PATH "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/bin" ndenv rehash 2>/dev/null ndenv() {   typeset command   command="$1"   if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then     shift   fi    case "$command" in   rehash|shell)     eval "`ndenv "sh-$command" "$@"`";;   *)     command ndenv "$command" "$@";;   esac } set -x PYENV_ROOT "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/pyenv" set -x PATH $PATH "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/bin" setenv PATH '/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/shims' $PATH setenv PYENV_SHELL fish . '/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/libexec/../completions/pyenv.fish' command pyenv rehash 2>/dev/null function pyenv   set command $argv[1]   set -e argv[1]    switch "$command"   case rehash shell     . (pyenv "sh-$command" $argv|psub)   case '*'     command pyenv "$command" $argv   end end set -x RBENV_ROOT "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/rbenv" set -x PATH $PATH "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/bin" setenv PATH '/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/shims' $PATH setenv RBENV_SHELL fish source '/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/libexec/../completions/rbenv.fish' command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null function rbenv   set command $argv[1]   set -e argv[1]    switch "$command"   case rehash shell     source (rbenv "sh-$command" $argv|psub)   case '*'     command rbenv "$command" $argv   end end
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
from sourcing file -
        called on line 60 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/eval.fish

in function “eval”
        called on line 15 of file ~/.config/fish/config.fish

from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
        called during startup

source: Error while reading file “-”
```

エラー内容をググってもどうにもならなかったので、config.fishの`eval`部分を`anenv init - fish`で表示される内容に変えてみました。

```
set -x PATH $HOME/.anyenv/bin $PATH

# anyenv init - fish で出てくる内容
source "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/libexec/../completions/anyenv.fish"
function anyenv
  set command $argv[1]
  set -e argv[1]

  command anyenv "$command" $argv
end

set -x GOENV_ROOT "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/goenv"
set -x PATH $PATH "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/goenv/bin"
export PATH="/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/goenv/shims:${PATH}"
goenv rehash 2>/dev/null
set -x NDENV_ROOT "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/ndenv"
set -x PATH $PATH "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/bin"
export PATH="/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/shims:${PATH}"

ndenv rehash 2>/dev/null
ndenv() {
  typeset command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "`ndenv "sh-$command" "$@"`";;
  *)
    command ndenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}

set -x PYENV_ROOT "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/pyenv"
set -x PATH $PATH "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/bin"
setenv PATH '/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/shims' $PATH
setenv PYENV_SHELL fish
. '/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/libexec/../completions/pyenv.fish'
command pyenv rehash 2>/dev/null

function pyenv
  set command $argv[1]
  set -e argv[1]

  switch "$command"
  case rehash shell
    . (pyenv "sh-$command" $argv|psub)
  case '*'
    command pyenv "$command" $argv
  end
end

set -x RBENV_ROOT "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/rbenv"
set -x PATH $PATH "/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/bin"
setenv PATH '/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/shims' $PATH
setenv RBENV_SHELL fish
source '/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/libexec/../completions/rbenv.fish'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
function rbenv
  set command $argv[1]
  set -e argv[1]

  switch "$command"
  case rehash shell
    source (rbenv "sh-$command" $argv|psub)
  case '*'
    command rbenv "$command" $argv
  end
end
```

こうしてfishを起動しても、また以下のエラーが出ます。どのように対応すれば良いのでしょうか？

```
'case' builtin not inside of switch block
~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 43):   case "$command" in
                                        ^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
        called during startup

source: Error while reading file “/home/vagrant/.config/fish/config.fish”
```

ちなみにanyenvは最新バージョンにアップデートしてあります。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/70857

Comment: 最初のエラーメッセージを見ると、`config.fish` の中で、`export PATH="/home/vagrant/.anyenv/envs/goenv/shims:${PATH}"` としている部分があり、`${PATH}` を `$PATH` に修正しなさい、と読めます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

バグといいますか、コードを見る限り、`goenv` や `ndenv` は `fish` に対応していないです。
想定しているのは`bash`、`ksh`、`zsh`です。
https://github.com/kaneshin/goenv/blob/master/libexec/goenv-init#L56
https://github.com/riywo/ndenv/blob/master/libexec/ndenv-init#L59

`pyenv` と `rbenv`は対応しているようです。
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/libexec/pyenv-init#L46
https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/libexec/rbenv-init#L35

metropolis さんがコメントで指摘している`${PATH}`の件も、

> 'case' builtin not inside of switch block

というエラーも、sh系の文法を `fish` に読ませた事が原因です。

---

解決策としては二つ、

- 自分で頑張って対応させる
- `bash` などで環境のスイッチをした後に `fish` を起動する

が考えられます。